# Traversing key/values of an NSDictionary, is enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock more efficient than looping keys and calling objectForkey:?

Tags: iphone, ios, performance, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks

I need to traverse all key/values pairs of a dictionary and do something with both fields. I am wondering what is more efficient, the traditional 'foreach key' approach or the blocks approach using enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:.

Here you have an example:

Traditional approach (before blocks)

```
for (NSString* key in [self.dictionary allKeys] ) {
    [self processKey:key value: [self.dictionary objectForKey:value ]];
}
```

Blocks approach.

```
 [self.dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
        [self processKey:key value:obj];
    }];
```

My gut feeling is that traversing the key/value pairs using the block is faster, but I am not sure since I don't know how dictionaries and the particular block method is implemented.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean objectForKey:key rather than objectForKey:value ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use the block based method. This is faster, as [shown here](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-04-09-comparison-of-objective-c-enumeration-techniques.html). In particular, it does not require an extra lookup in the dictionary to grab the value, which saves performance. However, performance gains will be negligible unless operating on reasonably-large dictionaries.

Answer (score 12):

They would be basically the same -- they are both synchronous traversals. However, the following would allow for concurrent traversal, which would be faster:

```
[self.dictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                              usingBlock:^(id key, id object, BOOL *stop) {

}];
```

Comment: The block method is quite a bit faster with large dictionaries, since it doesn't require generating a hash from every key, which is pretty slow. See `CFStringHashNSString()` here: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-476.17/CFString.c